# BIND IPv6 not responding to remote requests

Tags: ipv6, bind

I have setup an IPv4 BIND server that returns both IPv4 and IPv6 IPs but when I try and setup just an IPv6 server it does not work for remote requests.

- This is my `named.conf`

  ```
  options {
          listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
          directory       "/var/named";
          dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
          statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
          memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
          recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
          secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
          allow-query     { any; }; }
  ```
- A query on the actual DNS server itself works

  ```shellsession
  [root@vms1 ~]# dig vms4.test.dcp.net AAAA

  ; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.13 <<>> vms4.test.dcp.net AAAA
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49929
  ;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2
  ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;vms4.test.dcp.net.             IN      AAAA

  ;; ANSWER SECTION:
  vms4.test.dcp.net.      3600    IN      AAAA    2a05:yyyy:yy:y::4

  ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
  test.dcp.net.           3600    IN      NS      dns1.test.dcp.net.

  ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
  dns1.test.dcp.net.      3600    IN      AAAA    2a05:xxxx:xx:x::3

  ;; Query time: 2 msec
  ;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
  ;; WHEN: Thu Jun 22 12:28:52 BST 2023
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 121
  ```
- and enabling "rndc querylog" the query is logged in `/var/log/messages`

  ```
  Jun 22 12:28:52 vms1 named[2163]: client @0x7fe9fc03b510 ::1#42120 (vms4.test.dcp.net): query: vms4.test.dcp.net IN AAAA +E(0) (::1)
  ```
- From a remote VM on a different IPv6 network (the VM can ping the DNS server over IPv6):

  ```shellsession
  [root@vms3 ~]# dig vms4.test.dcp.net AAAA

  ; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.13 <<>> vms4.test.dcp.net AAAA
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
  ```

  and there is nothing in `/var/log/messages` for the query.
- A `tcpdump` on the DNS server shows the query getting to the server

  ```shellsession
  [root@vms1 log]# tcpdump  -n -l -i eth0 port 53
  tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
  listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
  12:33:02.167116 IP6 2a05:yyyy:yy:y::3.40289 > 2a05:xxxx:xx:x::3.domain: 16288+ [1au] AAAA? vms4.test.dcp.net. (46)
  ```

On the DNS server I have disabled and removed `firewalld` and there is no firewall blocking any packets as far as I can tell.

The servers are all running CentOS 7.

This is a test environment so I can make any changes etc. and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `dig @DNSSERVERIP vms4.test.dcp.net AAAA` -> https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig

Comment: You also want `allow-recursion { any; };`

Comment: Tried specifying the server in the dig command but the DNS query is going to the correct server already.  It got the same result.

Comment: Added the recursion and still no luck.

Comment: Thanks to both responders. It just seems that something is blocking the DNS query getting to the BIND process but there is no firewall etc. running and IPv4 BIND setup  works fine.